# Linux top in RES what does the 't' suffix stand for

Tags: performance, memory-usage, top

When monitoring my system with top, I noticed that under RES some values have a 't' suffix, but I can't see any indication of what this means.

```
  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                                                     
37393 libvirt+  20   0 15.100g 0.012t   4992 S 105.5  9.7 151:05.32 qemu-system-x86                                                                                             
42545 libvirt+  20   0 15.433g 0.012t   4984 S  96.2  9.8 189:08.01 qemu-system-x86                                                                                             
 6191 ceilome+  20   0  199236  35632   4432 S  13.6  0.0 687:02.55 ceilometer-agen                                                                                             
 6198 nova      20   0 4934088 366448   7040 S   8.6  0.3   1166:39 nova-compute                                                                                                
17270 libvirt+  20   0 10.159g 5.534g   4060 S   3.6  4.4 892:11.44 qemu-system-x86
```

For example the top 2 processes have a value of RES of 0.012t.  The 5th is using 5.534 gigabytes which is clear.

Can anyone give me an explanation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"t" == Terabytes. Move the decimal three places to the right, and you have 12GB.